# Optimizing data fetch for efficient load time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm new to iOS development and I'm having trouble figuring out how to efficiently load my app's data at launch time. My app consists of a UITableView that is populated with a list of songs. Each cell displays data about the song: current user rating(if rated) and avg. user rating (avg. rating of all users). I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) for my backend data storage.

At launch time, my app runs two queries. The first query fetches songs to populate the table. It then calculates the avg. user rating (my backend schema includes count objects: rating1_count, rating2_count, etc. which are incremented when the user rates a song). It also orders the songs into separate data model arrays: topTracksOfTheWeek, topTracksOfTheMonth, topTracksAllTime.

The second query fetches all of the rated songs by the current user. It then compares this query to the first query to embed the user rating data into the first query to form the app's data model.

I'd like to limit the first query to 50 songs to optimize load time. However, with my current data model, I need to query all of the songs in my database to calculate all of the avg. user ratings and then order the songs into the topTracks arrays.

The only solution I can come up with is running a server-side script periodically to calculate the avg. user ratings. I would have to create a new class in my database for the topTracks arrays that are ordered by the script. In my app, I would lazily do a third query for the topTracks arrays.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain your "average user rating" algorithm a bit.  Does changing the rating of "Hound Dog" affect the rating of "Somebody to Love"?

Comment: No, one song's avg. rating has no affect on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not minimize both client and server side operations by a) storing and recalculating average rating when the new rating is added b) get the songs ordered and paged, order type and page size could be either supported with different queries or the same query parameters.

Ideally you don't make any calculations on the mobile device if that could be calculated on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, seems to me that you could design the rating algorithm such that you could assign a new rating to a song when it's rated, then just query the first 50 songs ordered by rating (be sure to build an index over rating).

Comment: Yes, this should work much better. What do you mean by build an index over rating?

Comment: I think that is about database indexing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index